# Add values into DataFrame Python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, dataframe

I'm trying to add values into the 'Overall' column using both if-else and for-loop, however it doesn't seem to work.

I'm using the values from the 'Total' Column of my DataFrame to determine the 'Overall'column value either a Pass or a Fail.]

```
    for index, row in Score.iterrows():
         if Score['Total']>=100:
            Score.insert(index,'Overall', 'Pass')
          else:
            Score.insert(index,'Overall', 'Fail')

        Name    Maths   English Total   Overall
    0   Tom        50   50      100 
    1   Jack       80   50      130 
    2   Tim        70   80      150 
    3   Hen         1   84      85
```

[Attached picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ133.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Score['Overall'] = Score['Total'].map(lambda x: 'Pass' if x>=100 else 'Fail')
```

Comment: Danche: I'm kindda curious what is the function of lambda x?

Comment: @user234568 The `lambda x` just define an function operation, you can also define a function named `func` separately and use `Series.map(func)`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using vectorized [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [128]: Score
Out[128]:
   Name  Maths  English  Total
0   Tom     50       50    100
1  Jack     80       50    130
2   Tim     70       80    150
3   Hen      1       84     85

In [129]: Score['Overall'] = np.where(Score['Total'] >= 100, 'Pass', 'Fail')

In [130]: Score
Out[130]:
   Name  Maths  English  Total Overall
0   Tom     50       50    100    Pass
1  Jack     80       50    130    Pass
2   Tim     70       80    150    Pass
3   Hen      1       84     85    Fail
```

Comment: MaxU How do you know whether it is numpy or pandas for where statement? I'm still quite new to python so I've a bit of confusion between numpy and pandas?